# django - default value based on a FK's value

Tags: python, django, model

I'm trying to define a default value of a field based on the value of a FK's field.
I've gave a search around and found this (it's adapted to my own models):

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Line, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if not self.id:
        self.max_payout = self.coin.LineMax()
```

Model "Line" references to model "Coin" this way:

```
coin = models.ForeignKey(Coin)
```

Error I'm getting when trying to compile is this:

```
Exception Type: RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /admin/acb_lines/line/add/
Exception Value: Line has no coin.
```

I'm guessing it's because when you start to add a Line, "Coin" is a dropdown menu with no value set yet.

[Edit]
I've come to avoid the RelatedObjectDoesNotExist error by adding a default value for Coin, yet the issue remains unresolved

Comment: move the `__init__` of `super` below your logic.

Comment: @AnkurAnkan: please don't use code spans (`like this`) for words that isn't code or a code keyword. For example, `def` or `__init__` should be in a code span, but `this really shouldn't be`. Thanks!

Comment: @karthikr I'm sorry, really new to this, could you provide an example?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy thanks for the edit, this is my first(ish) post on Stack

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're creating your `Line` before your `Coin`. Perhaps you can switch this. If not, consider setting `Line.max_payout` in `Coin.__init__` instead. Otherwise, override the `save()` function to include this logic. However, know that if you do that it would be set on batch actions and setting the value will be delayed until you save the object to the database, which could be an issue if you are creating objects programmatically (rather than through the form).

Comment: `Coin` is created already (I need it to create the line), I added a default value for coin but still not working.
My main issue here was to set a default value for the user, and then he/she could decide wether to modify it or not.
The idea behind it would be before it is saved to the database